# How to send e-mail with yahoo pipes?

Tags: email, rss, yahoo-pipes

I would like to send every new feed item almost real-time to a specific e-mail address. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have created a pipe you can use a service such as [RSSFWD](http://www.rssfwd.com/index.aspx) to deliver it to your email.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, once you've built and saved your pipe, run it and you'll get the RSS URL of the output of your pipe.

To get RSS feed updates mailed to you, I prefer a service like [Blogtrottr](https://blogtrottr.com/). Blogtrottr is very easy to setup as it does not require you to register an account with the service. You just need the RSS URL and the email address to subscribe to the RSS feed. However with Yahoo Pipes, Blogtrottr offers a [daily update only](https://blogtrottr.com/help/#limited_domains) - which I do not call "almost real time".

For Yahoo Pipes I recommend [FeedMyInbox](https://www.feedmyinbox.com) which offers an hourly update. I'd consider this "almost real time".

On a side note: I compared RSSFWD with Blogtrotter on a busy RSS feed. While Blogtrotter reported every hour, RSSFWD reported every 30 minutes. Blogtrotter sends each new feed element as a separate mail whereas RSSFWD sends the update in form of a digest as a single mail.